# Django changelist on instance click redirect to a instance's foreign key model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have 2 models:

```
class Offer:
    code = ...
    company = ....

class Product:
    price = models.DecimalField
    name = models.CharField
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
```

in admin, on the changelist view that displays all the Products instances, i want that when you click on a Product instance, you will be redirected on the changeview for editing the Offer pointed by the Product's foreign key.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you don't want to be able to get to Product's changeview at all? I think then you can pretty much just remove Product from admin site, and use Offer's admin instead.

Comment: No, i want that when I click on a product, instead of opening a product, I want to open the offer which is pointed by this product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `change_view` method of the `ModelAdmin`, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from yourapp.models import Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        return redirect(
            "admin:yourapp_offer_change",
            args=(Product.objects.get(pk=object_id).offer.pk,)
        )

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Replace `yourapp` with the name of the Django application in which you have your `Offer` and `Product` models.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, even if I used this solution:

return redirect('/gestionale/technicians/contracttech/%s' % str(ProductHaccp.objects.get(id=object_id).offer.id))

Thank you very much!

Comment: @exrezzo generally it is never good to specify URLs as-is in Django. You should use `reverse` function, `{% url %}` template tag, etc. More on it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls